# How do I link two parse tables per common field?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a simple relationship between two parse tables (objects).

Both contain a 'name' string column. 
All I need to do is to create a join between the two tables per 'name' column.

For example:

Table A (main) <--> Table B (ancillary)
where
'A.name' == 'B.name'.

Table A is the driving table: all criteria focuses on Table A.  
Table B is the ancillary table that has a particular field (column) needed for Table A's result.

Note: the tables don't have any formal relation with each other.

What is the correct Parse syntax to allow this to happen?

 ...or must I make two queries instead on one merged query?

Comment: Why don't you add a pointer instead of duplicating the name?

Comment: I didn't design the table.

Comment: I believe I can.  I'm studying parse relationship now.